# Upload image to server using okhttp

Tags: android, http-post, image-uploading, okhttp

I'm using OKhttp for network requests. Trying to upload an image to a server. This is the way I tried, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("", "",
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), encodedImage))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(serverUrl)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "But it is not working" : How is it "Not working"? Crash? No connection? You have to be more detailed and if there is a crash, add logcat

Comment: If you are trying to get things done faster, use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) instead. If you really want to get help, please give some more details like logcat.

Comment: Why are you base64-encoding the image?

Comment: Using an empty string for your form data part name is also likely a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to base64-encode the image data, just use `byteArray`:

```
.addFormDataPart("image", "filename.jpg",
                 RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*jpg"), byteArray))
```

Comment: Isn't that sending the whole bitmap across the network then?